# Magento 2.4.4 with php 8.1 issue

Tags: magento2.4.4, php8

I have version 8.1.3 of PHP and I am getting the following error message on Magento 2.4.4:

```
    Exception #0 (Exception): Deprecated Functionality: strtotime(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($datetime) 
of type string is deprecated in /data/web/magento2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Stdlib/DateTime/Timezone.php on line 259
```

on the homepage, category pages etc. Have you faced this issue before ? Do you have any suggestions how to fix it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing both these things

- PHP fpm all extensions
- Composer version

You can also rename the vendor and update the composer.

Comment: not sure if what you said has any impact on the issue described. Can you add some more details ? Please note that on PHP 7.4 this doesn't occur.

Comment: I think this link may be helpful for you: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/34531. You can also check my deleting the vendor directory and run the composer update. If it is a fresh installation, you can fix this issue by the above related solutions

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i can't understand why this issue getting in core modules but i was facing same issue like `PHP Deprecated: explode():`. So i have found temporary solution for it.

Below is that us my issue solution.

```
$comp_uids = explode(',', $result['comp_uids'] ?? '');
```

And i am not sure about you issue but try below solution once time.

```
return strtotime($date) ?? '';
```

Check below links:

**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71707325/migration-to-php-8-1-how-to-fix-deprecated-passing-null-to-parameter-error-r**

**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71097927/php-8-1-explode-passing-null-to-parameter-2-string-of-type-string-is-de**

**`Thanks.`**